# Can't dynamically cast a collection of objects to a type known at runtime

Tags: c#

I know this question was here multiple times but i did some searching and i couldn't find solution that would fit:

```
private void UpdateCollections<T>(ICollection<T> updatedFormulas, 
    ICollection<T> currentFormulas) where T: IIdentifiable
{
    // Irrelevant code omitted

    foreach (var prop in newOrUpdatedFormula.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(string) &&
            prop.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable).Name) != null &&
            prop.GetValue(newOrUpdatedFormula) != null)
        {
            // the dynamic type i need is stored here =>
            // prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]

            UpdateCollections((ICollection<??>prop.GetValue(newOrUpdatedFormula), 
                (ICollection<??>prop.GetValue(existingFormula));
        }
    }
}
```

I need to go through two collections of objects to compare them. inside of those two collections there are other sub-collections of different type (but still implementing IIdentifiable interface). It goes this way few levels deep. So the '??' type i know at runtime and i know it implements IIdentifiable.

I've tried casting to `ICollection<IIdentifiable>` and it didn't work, i've tried to play with `MakeGenericType`() method but also it didn't help.

Something like below won't even compile:

```
Type typeInCollection = typeof(ICollection<>)
    .MakeGenericType(prop.PropertyType.GenericTypeArguments[0]) 

UpdateCollections(Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(newOrUpdatedFormula), 
    typeInCollection), Convert.ChangeType(prop.GetValue(existingFormula), typeInCollection));
```

What's the easiest way to make this recursive method work when i know the type inside ICollection at runtime?

Comment: What are `newOrUpdatedFormula` and `existingFormula`? Are they `T`?

Comment: In any case: Generics and reflection don't mix well. One option is "visitor" pattern, where each class implementing `IIdentifiable` has a `UpdateMe()` method which passes each of its own `IIdentifiable` collections to `UpdateCollections<T>()`, and `UpdateCollections<T>()` does little more than call `UpdateMe()` on whatever's passed in. You could also do a lot of MakeGenericMethod and MakeGenericType stuff to make this work. You don't want to be calling ChangeType then. You'll be creating generic methods and calling invoke, passing parameters as `object`.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes, those two parameters are of type T. If it's impossible, I'll try to find an alternative solution. Something close to what you've described.

Comment: It's absolutely possible to do this with reflection. It's just a bit awkward and inconvenient and not very readable. Also if the collections get pretty big, there's some extra overhead that might start to matter. The visitor pattern is no paradise for readability either, but at it uses generics right.

Comment: Why you just don't construct UpdateCollections generic method with reflection and invoke it? Am I missing something?